# Get all child in xml via powershell without named tag

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to use powershell to load an xml and show all the names of the nodes without set parent. Is this possible?

Here's my code so far:

```
[xml]$changesXML = Get-Content $PathToXML
function ReplaceOneFormat
{
    Param(
        $Parent
    )
    foreach($child in $Parent)
    {
        $child.Name?
        #ReplaceOneFormat $child # call this function by recursive
    }
}

ReplaceOneFormat $changesXML
```

So, this is my example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
  <book author="a">1</book>
  <book author="b">2</book>
  <book author="c">
    <page>796</page>
    <language>USA</language>
    <Publisher>USAFM</Publisher>
  </book>
  <journal>L2</journal>
  <journal>
    <book author="d">L3</book>
    <Publisher>USAFM</Publisher>
  </journal>
</books>
```

And I need result like this:

```
    Node:       Value:  
    books       
    book        1
    book        2
    book        
    page        796
    language    USA
    Publisher   USAFM
    journal     L2
    journal 
    book        L3
    Publisher   USAFM
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Interesting question. I have same task, but I can't do, what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create example, to loop in all node. Hope this is help for you!

```
[xml]$changesXML = Get-Content $NameFile
$tmp = $changesXML.SelectNodes("//*")
$cnt = $tmp.Count

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $tmp.Count; $i++) {
 "Attributes:"+$tmp.Item($i).Attributes
 "BaseURI:"+$tmp.Item($i).BaseURI
 "ChildNodes:"+$tmp.Item($i).ChildNodes
 "InnerText:"+$tmp.Item($i).InnerText
 "Name:"+$tmp.Item($i).Name
 "LocalName:"+$tmp.Item($i).LocalName
 "NamespaceURI:"+$tmp.Item($i).NamespaceURI
 "NodeType:"+$tmp.Item($i).NodeType
 "Prefix:"+$tmp.Item($i).Prefix
 "**********************************************"
}
```